# Where can I get the complete list of word entries present in Merriam Webster's dictionary?

Tags: corpora, dictionary

I can't find any list, github repo, etc to find the total list of entries defined in merriam webster. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Understandably, they don't just give that away for free.  They do have an API and offer licensing on a case-by-case basis.

Try Wiktionary

Comment: Is there a way to get a list of words in Wiktionary? As I understand it is to be used on a case-by-case routine too.

Comment: Yes, there are data dumps and parsing libs available. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wiktionary